# How to check in CAPL if message is receiving in simulation or not?

Tags: python, c, can-bus, capl, canoe

I want check in CAPL if the message is receiving or not in the simulation and if it is not coming in the trace, i want send new message. I have tried using functions like. I want to check particular message is receving or not?
TestWaitForPDU();TestWaitFormessage(msg,2000) etc but in simple configuration these are not working.

I have also tried using istimerActive() or istimerunning(), but these function will not check if message has stopped receiving or transmitting.

I am working in generic node.and i have tried something like this

```
on timer tslpack
{
  int sleepack;
   long Systemtime[9];
  sleepack= isTimerActive(tslpack);
   //write("Bus Active");
    
 // write("Running Status %d",tslpack.isRunning());
 

 

        if(sleepack==1)
          {
            write("timer cancelled");
            cancelTimer(tslpack);
            Settimer(tslpack,100);
          }
          else
          {
            result=1;
        if(result ==1)
        {
         
        write("Bus Sleep");
          sleeptime=timeNow();
    
    
      
       result = 0;
       }

}
```

Comment: Hello, welcome to SO. Please take your time to properly format your question, and maybe add an example script you tried and is not working. Are you working in a test case, or in a generic node?

Comment: Hi, i am working in generic node not testcase

Comment: I have written some thing like this,but it is not working

Comment: on timer tslpack
{
  int sleepack;
   long Systemtime[9];
  sleepack= isTimerActive(tslpack);
   //write("Bus Active");
    
 // write("Running Status %d",tslpack.isRunning());
  if(sleepack==1)
  {
    write("timer cancelled");
    cancelTimer(tslpack);
    Settimer(tslpack,100);
  }
  else{
    result=1;
if(result ==1)
    {
     
    write("Bus Sleep");
      sleeptime=timeNow();


  
   result = 0;
   }

Comment: the code makes little sense...you are setting timers, a large part of the implementation isn't shown. Please read this on [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and maybe a basic tutorial on CAPL. I can't see any effort in reaching the desired goal, I see random spaghetti

Answer (score 0):

You have mentioned that you are not writing the code in Test Node and you want to do it in Simulation Node. Clearly the functions `TestWaitForPDU();TestWaitFormessage(msg,2000)` are supposed to be used in tests as the name of the function shows.
I suppose you are waiting for a CAN message and so I am giving you a sample code for it.

```
variables
{
  msTimer TimerToCheckMessage;
  message CAN1.0x123 TxMsg;    //Message which you want to send
}

on start
{
  setTimer(TimerToCheckMessage,103);
  TxMsg.dlc = 4;
}

on message CAN1.0x1            //Message which you want to check
{
  setTimer(TimerToCheckMessage,103);
}

on timer TimerToCheckMessage
{
  output(TxMsg);
  setTimer(TimerToCheckMessage,103);
}
```